# How to make an easy password login with Java

Tags: java, passwords, jpanel

For a school project I need to come up with some easy programming codes, but ones that are challenging you as well...

Now here's the thing;
I need to make with Java -> JFrame Form a game, on which you need to login with a password. If wrong, you can re-do it. If right, you will get to continue to the game.

Here's the code I came up with some far... dont laugh about me.. I'm a Rookie

```
public kleurFrame() {
    initComponents();
          JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password?");
   String geheugen;
   geheugen = JOptionPane.INPUT_VALUE_PROPERTY;
   String password;
   password = "Hay";
   while(geheugen != password){
       JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password?");
   if (geheugen == password){
       JOptionPane.EXIT and continue program;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password?");`is useless, it will just show a dialog for which the value is ignored, Secondly `geheugen = JOptionPane.INPUT_VALUE_PROPERTY;` points on a constant, it doesn't get the typed password, Here I come whith an attempt to match your needs, I hope it helps :

```
public void kleurFrame() {
    initComponents();
    String geheugen = null ;
    String password = "Hay"; // even if it is a bad practice to hardcode a password !!
    while (!password.equals(geheugen)) {
        geheugen = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Password?");
    }
// once the blocking loop ended, that means 
// the password is correct and you can exit 
// the dialog and continue normally

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null/*or the calling component*/,"the password is correct, now you can continue",
            "this is just an example",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: When using your code and running the program, it only shows a tiny bar in top-left of my screen (no pop-up message etc.)